# ffmpeg dash playback stream ends too early

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, mpd

I am trying to play back a dash manifest using `ffmpeg` but I keep running into the issue of `ffmpeg` ending with the error

```
[http @ 0x671e580] Stream ends prematurely at 2250, should be 18446744073709551615
```

The dash manifest is for a livestream.

I have tested the live stream in VLC player on Windows and MX player on Android and it plays perfectly fine. 
The issue seems to be just with `ffmpeg`.

Has anyone had this issue before or know what the cause may be?

I have tried telling `ffmpeg` to reconnect but it just loops this error. 
I have tried two different MPD live streams:

- `$Time$` based, and
- `$Number$` based

The issue happens only with the Number based live stream.

Answer (score 0):

Hi did you find a solution to this issue i have an mpd that plays perfect in everything vlc/mx/exo/shaka player the lot but it refuses to open in ffplay and ffmpeg i get the same error as you followed by io/error unable to read manifest

i have tested the manifest against the online dash validation tools and it passes with no problems and works with everything but ffmpeg

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/420803)

Comment: P.S.  Are you "Bluchip"?